# Bash simple string parse

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Given this format:

```
DISKGROUP NAME    GB ALLOCATED         GB USED         GB FREE       USABLE GB PCT USED STATUS                          
-------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- -------- --------------------            
DISK_1             1,117.40          390.48          726.92          223.78    34.95 MOUNTED                         
DISK_2         1,117.40           65.97        1,051.43          386.04     5.90 MOUNTED
```

With a single bash command how can I reliably get the value from GB FREE? The number of spaces between fields can very based on the field size, so I can't specify a static number of spaces with cut. Is there a way to use spaces as delimiter, but have the number of spaces be a variable size?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "GB FREE\n--------"} NR>2{print $4}' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Explanation:

1. We use `awk's BEGIN` statement to print the heading which is `GB FREE and -------`. This is because the heading in your input file has spaces in the titles. This can throw the `awk` script off.
2. Second, we use `awk's` built-in variable `NR` which stores the line number. Since we don't want line 1 and 2 to be printed, we keep a condition of `NR>2`. This way awk will skip the first two lines and start printing from line 3.
3. In `awk` by default, the delimiter or Field separator is spaces (one or more). Since your file has that we don't need to set the `FS` built-in variable. Each field separated by a space becomes a column and can be accessed using `$` and `column number`. Since you want the `GB FREE` column which is 4, we do `print $4`.
4. To keep more conditions, like printing only those lines where `column 1` has `DISK_2` we add another pattern statement. Using `NR>2 && $1~/DISK_2/` ensures we don't print lines 1 and 2 and look for lines where `column 1` has `DISK_2` in them and print the `column 4` of those lines.

#### Note: If you don't really care about the heading part, you can shorten this one-liner to the following (depending on your requirement):

```
awk 'NR>2{print $4}' INPUT_FILE
```

**or**

```
awk 'NR>2 && $1~/DISK_2/{print $4}' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
DISKGROUP NAME    GB ALLOCATED         GB USED         GB FREE       USABLE GB PCT USED STATUS                          
-------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- -------- --------------------            
DISK_1             1,117.40          390.48          726.92          223.78    34.95 MOUNTED                         
DISK_2         1,117.40           65.97        1,051.43          386.04     5.90 MOUNTED   

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'BEGIN {print "GB FREE\n--------"} NR>2{print $4}' file
GB FREE
--------
726.92
1,051.43
```

#### To add filters as stated in the comments:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'BEGIN {print "GB FREE\n--------"} NR>2 && $1~/DISK_2/{print $4}' file
GB FREE
--------
1,051.43
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! Say I wanted to only return the value of DISK_2 using your command, how could I further filter the result?

Comment: Updated the answer @Hoofamon. `awk` by default works on one or more space as delimiter. Each field becomes a column that can be accessed using `$` and the `column number`. Since you wanted to print `GB Free` column, we used `$4`. To print only line with `Column 1` having `DISK_2` we added a condition `$1~/DISK_2/`. :)

Comment: A question that got deleted later: Q) Isn't `awk '{print $4}'` sufficient? A) It is but it will also print the `4th field` of the `first line or the heading` which is `ALLOCATED`. We can shorten it to `awk 'NR>2{print $4}' file` if you'd like, but printing the heading looks nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1,2d;s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/' file
```

as above with headings:

```
sed '1,2c\ GB FREE\n--------'$'\n'';s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/' file
```

or for `DISK_2` only:

```
sed '/^DISC_2/s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/p;d' file
```

as above with heading:

```
 sed '/^DISK_2/s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/;s/^/ GB FREE\n--------\n/p;d' file
```